# Forward arrow operator not found

Tags: r, operators, assignment-operator

I'm confused with the nature of `->`, I cannot get its definition like I can with other operators and it doesn't behave like `<-`. See below:

```
print(`<-`) # .Primitive("<-")
print(`->`) # Error in print(`->`) : object '->' not found
```

Also, I can't hijack it, though R won't fire any error if I try to :

```
`->` = `+`  # attempting to hijack `->`, no error
print(`->`) # function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("+"), seems like it worked
1 -> 3      # Error in 3 <- 1 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
1 -> test1
print(test1) # 1, hijacking failed
`->`(1,3)   # 4, this works
```

With `<-` (or any other operator I tried), I can do it:

```
`<-` = `+`   
print(`<-`)
1 <- 3      # 4
1 <- test2  # Error: object 'test2' not found

rm(list=ls()) # back to sanity
```

So what's going on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> e <- quote(42 -> x)
> e
x <- 42
```

There is only one assignment operator in R: `<-` (well, two: there's `=` but let's not complicate things). The *parser* interprets the symbol "`->`" as assignment, and creates the expression as if `<-` had been used.

Answer (score 2):

More a comment than an answer, but it was maybe to long.

It seems that the `->` is handled by the parser, which detects the left and right side of the assignment and then calls `<-`. Following your hacks:

```
`<-` = `+`
1 -> 3
#[1] 4
```

See what happened? There is basically no time to the `->` operator to act, since the parser doesn't allow it, unless you call it explicitly:

```
`->` = `+`
`->`(5,6)
#[1] 11
```